# Problem downloading large lfs files with git clone from github

Tags: git, github, git-lfs

In this github repo:

https://github.com/jerabaul29/Cylinder2DFlowControlDRL

the author made available a container, sliced in small chunks so that they are accepted by github, tracked using git-lfs. However, it seems that some users have problems reconstructing the container after a git clone, see:

https://github.com/jerabaul29/Cylinder2DFlowControlDRL/issues/19

I have tried myself, and the github cloning of the repo hang up and after an hour or so of doing nothing so I just killed it. As a result, the assembled container got corrupted. Following the method recommended on the readme there after the bug report, i.e. downloading the fragments using the web GUI, I got everything downloaded in the course of a few minutes and I managed to assemble a non corrupted container and run everything.

I think this problem with data obtained from cloning is a bit strange.

- any idea why cloning the repo does not seem to work? Is it due to the repo being set up in a wrong way and should the repo owner fix something, or is it due to my machine, or a github problem?
- any way to fix this, so that issuing a simple git clone would clone the full repo including all segments? It looks like the segments data are well available, as it is possible to download these through the github web GUI...

Comment: I don't know what is wrong with the repository or those files, but in response to "should the author do something else". Yes, he should. He should store the scripts and recipes and whatnot that he uses to *build* the container, instead of the actual container.

Comment: I definitely agree. The challenge is, the author may not have been the person building the container, he may not have access to the recipe etc. For example, it is quite common at universities that you get an old container from a colleague, or a container from the IT department, and build a bit on it for a project.